# Jquery Delete Row Table Bug in my Code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have somehow managed to Code a working system to delete a row from a Table retrieved from Database.

There is a problem with my code which i couldnt correct

Jquery function to delete and slide up the row

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

                $.post('delete.php', {id:del_id},function(data){
                    parent.slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is the PHP code for the Retrieved Table

```
<?php
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "
        <td>
            <span class='label label-red'>".$row['lid']."</span>
        </td>                                
        <td>
            ".$row['name']."
        </td>    
        <td>
            <a href='#'>".$row['email']."</a>
        </td>       
        <td>
            ".$row['tel']."
        </td>    
        <td>
            Mental Stress Relief
        </td>  
        <td>
            <a href=\"javascript:return(0);\" id=".$row['lid'].">Delete</a>
        </td>
    ";
}
?>
```

Everythings working fine.

But the Navigation Menu uses the same `<a>` tag, So when I click the navigation link from this page .. its slides up just as the table row. I couldnt navigate... Should i Use ID or something??

```
<ul class="navigation">            
    <li><a href="dashboard.php" class="blblue">Statistics</a></li>
    <li><a href="leads.php" class="blyellow">Lead Detials</a></li>
    <li><a href="includes/logout.php" class="blred">Logout</a></li>                
</ul>
```

I am confused. What to do?

Comment: add class into close button tag like as `<a href="javascript;void(0)" class="delete_row"></a>' and `$('a').click(function(){` line change into `$(".delete_row").click(function(){`

Comment: @Ahosan Karim Asik: There is more than one row, so that would duplicate IDs, which is invalid and will not work :(

Comment: There is some inconsistency in the quoting of the attributes in the row. You may also want to make them consistent (double-quotes all the way for attributes is standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to identify the various types of link. e.g. `class="delete"` and change your code to target that:

```
 $(function () {
     $('a.delete').click(function () {
         if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
             var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
             var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
             $.post('delete.php', {
                 id: del_id
             }, function (data) {
                 $tr.slideUp('slow', function () {
                     $(this).remove();
                 });
             });
         }
         return false;
     });
 });
```

PHP changed to:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="delete" id=".$row['lid'].">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Notes:

- You have quotes around document in the DOM ready handler. They are not needed. I have instead used the *shortcut* version of the DOM ready handler, which is `$(function(){...});`
- Add a `delete` class to any "delete links" (obviously not to any other links). Classes can be used to imply specific behavior on elements (from a jQuery perspective). When there are multiple elements you should avoid using ID, or partial-ID, selectors.
- using `parent().parent()` is "fragile coding" and does not cope with HTML changes, so target a specific ancestor element with `closest()` instead (e.g. the `closest("tr")`)
- I renamed `parent` to the more meaningful `$tr` in the example, as I assume it is the row you remove.
- I use the `$` prevfix for jQuery object variables, for readability.
- You do not need the `href=\"javascript:return(0);\"` in your link. Change it to a simple `#` bookmark link.

Answer (score 1):

Change below line form :

```
$('a').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('td a').click(function(){
```

Comment: If another table is added to the page, this will fail. It needs to target more explicitly (e.g. a specific table id?)

Comment: Yeah, but OP, asper OP question I have answered simple way, if any any a.delete place in the same page your logic also will fail.. ohhh?

Comment: Yes, but you have control over adding the `delete` class *where it belongs*. It will have inherent meaning to the code. This code provides no scoping. This was just a suggestion, feel free to ignore advice and keep it *simple*. :)

Comment: I agree that, no need to argue, I tried to give a simple solution, thatz all.

Comment: *I* was not arguing, just stating facts the way I see them. How you respond to suggestions/criticism is up to you (usually people improve their answer and just say "thanks") :)